# Use array to vary the row/column in an offset in Excel formula

Tags: arrays, excel, offset

Looking for a way to use an array of numbers as the offset entry in an OFFSET formula.

Data setup:
- I have a table with three columns that represent low/medium/high options
- I want to add a fourth column where the user enters 1/2/3 as their low/medium/high selection
- I want to then have a cell at the bottom that sums up the selection options

Example

[image]

- User inputs in yellow cells
- Formula goes in orange cell
- Formula should output the sum of the green cells which are the choices in each row per the yellow cell

I have tried array formula variations of {=SUM(OFFSET([column 0],0,[column 4]))} i.e. set the anchor for the offset as one column left of the "low" options column and then the numbers 1/2/3 in column 4 to feed in as the column offset

Any ideas?

Comment: Have also tried using SUM(INDEX(etc)) where the array goes in as the index for each row but couldn't get that going either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to force INDEX to use an array as input:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:D,N(IF({1},ROW(B3:D5))),N(IF({1},(F3:F5)))))
```

Depending on ones's version of Excel this will need to confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

[image]

---

If one has a subscription to Office 365 that has the dynamic array formula, Microsoft fixed the need for the forcing the array:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B:D,ROW(B3:D5),F3:F5))
```

Comment: I saw you made an edit - the first version with INDEX(B3:D5) worked perfectly.

Very impressed, cheers!